# Should server IP address be in ALLOWED_HOSTS django setting?

Tags: django

Since upgrading to django 1.5 my logs show several `SuspiciousOperation` exceptions with the text:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): <my server's ip>
```

Is this genuinely a 'suspicious' request, or should I always be including my server's IP address in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting in addition to my domain name?  Any idea what would be making requests with `HTTP_HOST = "ip address"` rather than `HTTP_HOST = "domain name"`?

Here is the request environment:

```
{'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': "'identity'",
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': "'close'",
 'HTTP_HOST': "'168.62.208.14'",
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL': "'https'",
 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': "'176.10.35.241'",
 'HTTP_X_SCHEME': "'https'",
 'PATH_INFO': "u'/'",
 'QUERY_STRING': "''",
 'RAW_URI': "'/'",
 'REMOTE_ADDR': "'127.0.0.1'",
 'REMOTE_PORT': "'45068'",
 'REQUEST_METHOD': "'GET'",
 'SCRIPT_NAME': "u''",
 'SERVER_NAME': "'168.62.208.14'",
 'SERVER_PORT': "'80'",
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': "'HTTP/1.0'",
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': "'gunicorn/0.14.6'",
 'gunicorn.socket': "'<socket._socketobject object at 0x7ab3b40>'",
 'wsgi.errors': '"<open file \'<stderr>\', mode \'w\' at 0x7f0c94810270>"',
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': "'<class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at 0x34eec80>'",
 'wsgi.input': "'<gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x2a0bf10>'",
 'wsgi.multiprocess': 'False',
 'wsgi.multithread': 'False',
 'wsgi.run_once': 'False',
 'wsgi.url_scheme': "'http'",
 'wsgi.version': '[1, 0]'}
```

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header

Comment: @yuwang The difference is with the linked question is in that case HTTP_HOST is google.com - so it is certainly suspicious.  In my case, the HTTP_HOST is my server's actual IP address, so I'm not sure if it is valid request or not.

Comment: Are those for normally valid requests?

Comment: @KrisKumler I'm not quite sure if these requests are valid, that's what I'm trying to figure out.  I've included the request data from one of these requests.  All of our valid requests usually have HTTP_HOST: domain, but maybe there is some reason for clients to make requests by IP address I'm not aware of?

Comment: Do any of your cron jobs access your site? Any other types of script-based access?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins There are cronjobs that run manage.py commands on the server itself, but no scripts/jobs making http requests to the server from the outside.  These SuspiciousOperation exceptions are not periodic (as you might expect with a cron job), but I've seen 7 of them in the last 11 days since upgrading to django 1.5.

Comment: I am seeing the same - my guess is it is web crawlers, robots - which simply crawl public IP's looking for websites - so I think it would be ok to allow them get your website - I imagine should they succeed they will then do a reverse lookup to determine your domain name.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**NO, IT SHOULDN'T.**

Usually it's not a secure way to configure your Django server. Sometimes, e.g., when testing your application, you may access it via direct IP address, but in there's no reason to disable log warnings.

My old answer was wrong, thanks to Max Malysh for pointing that out.

**Old answer (INSECURE):**

<strike>Short answer is: YES (according to provided headers).</strike>

Long answer:
According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS):

> If the Host header (or X-Forwarded-Host if USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST is enabled) does not match any value in this list, the django.http.HttpRequest.get_host() method will raise SuspiciousOperation.

In other words: if your requests pass your server ip address as Host header (and apparently they do), and you think it's okay, then YES, you should add server ip to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

**Also**, ip address could be in HTTP_HOST for [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893351/ip-address-in-http-host) [reasons](http://forums.isaserver.org/fb.aspx?m=50314810), also someone could directly ask for ip address.

Comment: Thanks for the response - it sounds like I don't actually want my server IP in ALLOWED_HOSTS.  I don't see it being recommended anywhere else, and I don't particularly care about supporting requests directly to the IP (these requests are infrequent, and my server's IP can change).  The only way I can seem to trigger this type of request myself is by going to https://<server ip>, which is not something I want to support.

Comment: Well, usually you should just redirect such requests to your domain name, but if you really sure that all such "direct" requests are invalid -- ignore them.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. In ECS with ELB's healthcheck for a specific docker instance, the request will come directly to that container's IP address. There's no other way, AFAICT, to check the health of a specific instance.

Answer (score 30):

### No, it shouldn't

By default, there are no reasons why IP address should be accepted as a valid HOST header. This message is a sign of a misconfigured production environment: such requests shouldn't reach the back-end.

Here's a post on security.stackexchange.com on [Host header poisoning & ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45687/what-does-djangos-allowed-hosts-variable-actually-do).

### What to do

Filter out all requests with an invalid HOST header before they reach django back-end.

### How to

Most likely you use `nginx` as a reverse proxy in front of django. If you don't use any reverse proxy at all (or you're using `runserver`), you have to (otherwise you're risking your security).

Add a default server block returning `444` at the top of your configuration. It should be the first server block in the configuration:

```
# File: /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com

upstream django_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

# Catch all requests with an invalid HOST header
server {
    server_name "";
    listen      80;
    return      444;
}

# Your config goes there
server {
    server_name  domain.com;
    listen       80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In practice, just edit the file `MyProjectName/settings.py` and add the host IP (IP address to the machine in which you're running Django) to the list `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, which by default is empty.

So, in your, case we would have before the changes:

```
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
...
```

After changes:

```
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['168.62.208.14'] #Make sure your host IP is a string
...
```

Run the server again and you should be good. Here's an example using the port 8000:

`python manage.py runserver 168.62.208.14:8000`

. Now if you go to your browser and enter the address http://168.62.208.14:8000, you should find yourself in the page "Congratulations on your first Django-powered page".

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer that makes no assumptions about my use case.

Comment: On production server it is better to follow Max Malysh’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45496458/470560).